# Installing local .whl files on Databricks cluster

Tags: airflow, databricks, azure-databricks, python-wheel, airflow-2.x

I am trying to connect to a databricks cluster and install a **local** python whl using DatabricksSubmitRunOperator on Airflow (v2.3.2) with following configuration. However, it doesn't work and throws a fileNotFound exception (I checked file path multiple times, file exists).

```
task1 = DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
    task_id = <task_id>,
    job_name = <job_name>,
    existing_cluster_id = <cluster_id>,
    libraries=[
        {"whl": "file:/<local_absolute_path>"}
    ]
)
```

While the [official documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/libraries.html#library) states that, for .whl files, only DBFS and S3 storage is supported, in Airflow, I see the following error message when prefix `file:/` is not attached:

```
Library installation failed for library due to user error. 
Error messages: Python wheels must be stored in dbfs, s3, adls, gs or as a local file. Make sure the URI begins with 'dbfs:', 'file:', 's3:', 'abfss:', 'gs:'
```

Is it possible install local .whl files on a databricks cluster?

Alternative approach I tried is to copy .whl to dbfs storage and install it from there. The problem with that is that installation status is stuck at "pending".

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly install or upload .whl file as shown in the below image.

[image: Ref1]

**or**

Follow this [**official document**](https://docs.databricks.com/libraries/notebooks-python-libraries.html) installing .whl packages.

Comment: I particularly need it to be installed from a local file (if possible) to avoid delays in local development.

Comment: @Dhrumil doesn't make any sense, in case of Dev testing as well you can plug it with your Git repo and can create git hooks on CICD tool of your choice to deploy the whl file.