# Azure Data Factory with Data Bricks Notebook Execute Pipeline Error

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-data-factory

I am trying to execute my databricks note book and linked service as execution Pool type of connection, also I have upload the Append libraries option for wheel format library in ADF but unable to execute our notebook via ADF and getting below error.

Run result unavailable: job failed with error message Library installation failed for library due to user error for whl:

> "dbfs:/FileStore/jars/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/prophet-1.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl"
> . Error messages: Library installation attempted on the driver node of
> cluster 1129-161441-xwjfzl6k and failed. Please refer to the following
> error message to fix the library or contact Databricks support. Error
> Code: DRIVER_LIBRARY_INSTALLATION_FAILURE. Error Message:
> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Process List(bash,
> /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/python_start_clusterwide.sh,
> /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/bin/pip, install,
> --upgrade, --find-links=/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages,
> /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prophet-1.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_6
> ... ***WARNING: message truncated. Skipped 195 bytes of output**

Kindly help us. and in linked in service, there is three types of option we have(Select cluster),
1.new job cluster
2.exixting interactive cluster
3.Existing instance pool

in production perspective which is the best, we do not have any job created in databricks and plan note book needs to trigger in adf to success the execution. please advice

Comment: Hello All, Any idea on my issues? still i could struggling this issues.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you install the wheel onto the interactive cluster (option 2).  This has nothing to do with Azure Data Bricks.

[Installing local .whl files on Databricks cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72778547/installing-local-whl-files-on-databricks-cluster)

See the above article for details.

Comment: we did all the required lib in local cluster but while trying to trigger ADF pipeline, we got Lib missing and so on error getting, is it anything to mandatory to add Lib in ADF side. because i can see there is option to append Lib in ADF notebook settings. please suggest.

Comment: Even if we add Append Lib option to select wheel based lib location we given, like "/dbfs/mypackage-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl".. etc but still our issues not yet resolve

Comment: Hi @crafty, could you please assist on my comments. it could be helpful for me

Comment: Sorry I did not respond earlier.  I came down with COVID 19.  Anyways, there are 3 ways to start a cluster.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-databricks-notebook  If you are using the first way, it has no idea about the cluster settings.  I suggest using an existing interactive cluster.  You must supply the cluster id.  Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Karthik from the error it is complaining about the library . This is what i could have done .

1. Cross check & make sure that the ADF is pointing the correct cluster .
2. If The cluster is correct , move on the cluster and open the notebook which you are trying to refer from ADF . try to execute that .
3. If the notebook works fine , go and stop the cluster and restart it again and run the notebook .
   My guess is that once the cluster goes into the idle mode and shutsdown and then when ADF starts the cluster , it is not able to find the library it needs .

Comment: I have tried in notebook the code working fine but via ADF if i try to trigger the notebook, there is third party lib which is called "from prophet import Prophet" this is throwing error

Comment: error
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prophet'